# nodejs process object not recognized

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I have this line of code in my file:

`import appRoutes from process.ROOTDIR + '/../app/routes.js';`

I am getting the error:

```
SyntaxError: /Users/bli1/Development/Javascript/ReviewWeb/server/api/helpers/isomorphic.js: Unexpected token (6:22)
  4 | import Router from'react-router';
  5 | import Log from'loglevel';
> 6 | import appRoutes from process.ROOTDIR + '/../app/routes.js';
```

Is there a way I can have a global `ROOTDIR` variable so I don't have to add `../../..` everywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The import name is always a string literal.

Depending on your module loader, you might make it resolve names like `/app/routes.js` using a given root directory though. Have a look at its docs and what hooks are supported.